# binary search tree assignment operator (recursion)

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-search-tree, assignment-operator

I'm having huge troubles understanding how to implement this.

Here is the prototype and implementation I've tried thus far (please note that two of the attempts are commented out - labeled (1) and (2)

```
//--- ADD PROTOTYPE OF ASSIGNMENT OPERATOR HERE
 // (1) void operator=(const BST<DataType> & origList);
 // (2) BST<DataType>& BST<DataType>::operator=(const BST& origList)
BST::operator=(const BST& origList);
```

Currently each one results with the following error:

```
home\visual studio 2010\projects\bst.h(139): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed.
```

Here is the implementation of the assignment operator:

```
//--- Definition of operator=
template <typename DataType>
BST<DataType>& BST<DataType>::operator=(const BST& origList)
{
 if (this != &origList)
 {
    copyTree(origList.myRoot, myRoot);
    destroy(myRoot);
 }
 return *this;
}
```

Here is the copyTree recursive function(s):

```
//--- Definition of copy constructor()
template <typename DataType>
BST<DataType>::BST(const BST<DataType> & origList)
{
 copyTree(origList.myRoot, myRoot);
}

//--- Definition of copyTree()
template <typename DataType>
void BST<DataType>::copyTree(BinNodePointer origRoot, BinNodePointer & subtreeRoot)
{
 if (origRoot == 0)
    subtreeRoot = NULL;
 else
 {
    subtreeRoot = new BinNode(origRoot->data);
    copyTree(origRoot->left, subtreeRoot->left);
    copyTree(origRoot->right, subtreeRoot->right);

    //origRoot = new BinNode(subtreeRoot->data);
    //copyTree(subtreeRoot->left, origRoot->left);
    //copyTree(subtreeRoot->right, origRoot->right);
 }
}
```

The copy constructor works beautifully, however the assignment operator I've failed to grasp what is needed here. Any help is greatly appreciated!

P.S. You may have noticed I have "origList", it should be named "origTree" however I'm borrowing this from my previously created constructors for LinkedLists.

Comment: Ravi thanks man, the code compiles! However there must be an issue with my logic as the program crashes when attempting to run the assignment operator with the following message:                                       Unhandled exception at 0x77c815de in binaryst_10.1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xfeeefef6.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
BST<DataType>& BST<DataType>::operator=(const BST& origList)
```

should be

```
BST<DataType>& BST<DataType>::operator=(const BST<DataType>& origList)
```

with following declaration in the class

```
BST<DataType>& operator=(const BST<DataType>& origList)
```